# When using RestSharp Method Visual Studio breaks

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, restsharp

I am having a pretty weird issue, earlier today I had a large amount of code working and running in Visual Studio, my form worked flawlessly. I went for lunch came back and tried to open it and nothing. It runs, there are 0 errors, it uses memory but it won't display the form. I have not changed anything as far as I am aware.

I have created a new Windows Form Application and re-written the code line by line, I have found what breaks it however I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is breaking it.

**Form1.cs broken**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace RestApiViewerWUG
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var client = new RestClient("http://notrelevent.whocares.com/api/v1/token");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic cmVzdDo5RGJSIypkQDQ=");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            request.AddParameter("text/plain", "userName=rest&password=xxxxxx&grant_type=password", ParameterType.RequestBody); 
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request); //THIS LINE BREAKS IT

            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
    }
}
```

**The issue**

Simply removing the line "IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);" fixes it and allows the form to appear.

**What have I tried?**

- I have ensured RestSharp is properly installed and referenced, I have
  even tried several versions of it.
- I have uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio 2015
- As already stated I have created an entire new project going line by line
- Breakpoints/writing to console/log does nothing, 0 anything will happen when that line is left in the code

**Other info**

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RestApiViewerWUG
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

The form:

Literally just textBox with the exact name of textBox1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short story is, you shouldn't be doing this type of thing in the *constructor*, do it after the form loads.

Then, if you there is a *timeout*, you aren't waiting for the form to load and can give feedback of the fact it's in progress, or if there is an `exception` you aren't tearing the *form*  down.

You would also catch any *exceptions*, and give some notification of the failure modes that might happen.

**Background**

A forms *constructor* runs before a form is loaded (rendered), so it's best not to do anything expensive in them, in fact this is true for any constructor. A constructor is for initializing the minimum state the class/struct needs to function.

In regards to a forms *constructor*, if there is a long running process that happens during the constructor, the form load is directly effected and won't show leaving the user (and you) to scratch your head wondering why the form isn't showing. Even worse, if there is an *unhandled exception* your form never loads

Comment: That definitely makes a lot of sense, I have tried a few things this morning though and the problem persists. Using a separate class works fine again until the second it runs the IRestResponse line, if that line is included the form refuses to load. I also tried throwing it in the TextChanged method, form loads but the second I type a letter in it freezes instantly. I guess I am just very dumbfounded by this as the very line worked perfectly yesterday morning.

Comment: To add further, even if placed inside a try-catch block the form refuses to load and no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I greatly apologize for this and appreciate the new knowledge I've learned.

The answer to my question was way too simple... A month ago I added a certificate to our api, however it never seemed to apply, others had complained about a similar issue with the product we are using on the server. I didn't think anything of it.

Yesterday they took the server offline for a few minutes to replace a PSU, once restarted... my certificate loaded in so now it's using https.

The reason it wouldn't "load" was actually because the timeout time to the server takes ~ 60 seconds so after waiting long enough populated.